# An integral formula and Poincaré duality

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

Our goal is to interpreting a formula:
$$
\int_{\Sigma_d} a_d =\int_{M_D} a_d \cup PD(\Sigma_d)
$$
where $a_d$ is a $d$-form on $\Sigma_d$ and $PD$ is the Poincare dual to the $\Sigma_d$. The $\Sigma_d$ is the submanifold of $M_D$, with $D>d$.

- Is this formula only true under certain conditions? Like  $a_d$ is closed?
- A simple proof for this formula.